# FutureBuilder inside a LayoutBuilder call future many times

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I just came to a situation while experimenting with `LayoutBuilder` and `FutureBuilder`. If I put the `FutureBuilder` inside a widget other than `LayoutBuilder` every thing is fine and future is resolved only once. But when I put `FutureBuilder` inside a `LayoutBuilder` the future is resolved infinitely and final widget is never drawn.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Photo View example',
      theme: theme,
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            return ImagePainter();
          }
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
} 


class ImagePainter extends StatelessWidget{
  Future<ui.Image> loadImage() async {
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("graphics/test.jpg");
    if (data == null) {
      print("data is null");
    } else {
      var codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());
      var frame = await codec.getNextFrame();
      return frame.image;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
                child: FutureBuilder(
        future: loadImage(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ui.Image> snapshot) {
          switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting : 
              return Center(child: Text("loading..."),);
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text("error: ${snapshot.error}"),);
              } else {
                print("data: ${snapshot.data}");
                return Placeholder(); //just for testing
              }
            }
          },
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

So it can be explained?, Or I am doing some thing wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by saying *"widget is never drawn"*? Is the error widget drawn?

Comment: I think you change the widget tree in your `FutureBuilder` and this leads to the rebuilding of the `LayoutBuilder`. As a result, this process is looped

Comment: @KirillShashov That is what I thought as well, but it does not seem like that from what I can see in the code.

Comment: No, as you can see in the code sample the Image Painter is returned without any changes to widget tree. Its in a loop all the time.

Comment: @NatwarSingh Were you able to solve it? I am facing similar issue.

Comment: No. I have changed to layout completely as my use case is solved by Image and transform widget.

Answer (score -1):

```
class ImagePainter extends StatelessWidget{
Future<ui.Image> loadImage() async {
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("graphics/test.jpg");
if (data == null) {
  print("data is null");
} else {
  var codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());
  var frame = await codec.getNextFrame();
  return frame.image;
}


}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
            child: FutureBuilder(
    future: loadImage(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ui.Image> snapshot) {
      switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting : 
            print("data: ${snapshot.data}");
          //return Center(child: Text("loading..."),);
        default:
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text("error: ${snapshot.error}"),);
          } /*else {
            print("data: ${snapshot.data}");
            return Placeholder(); //just for testing
           }*/
         }
        },
      ),
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: The issue is when you put Future builder inside a layout builder.